# How can I run a script before RPM file creation?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, rpm, rpm-maven-plugin

I'm using rpm-maven-plugin to create an rpm of a tarball containing the WARs from my project.  I can create an rpm if I already have a tar file.  However, I would like to generate the tar file when I run the rpm goal.

I have a script that creates the tar file.  I call the script in the prepare step, however the rpm has already been created when the script executes, thus the tar is not included in my rpm.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1-alpha-4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-rpm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>rpm</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mappings>
          <mapping>
            <directory>/foo</directory>
            <sources>
                <source>
                    <location>DIRECTORY_FOR_MY_TAR</location>
                </source>
            </sources>
          </mapping>
        </mappings>
        <defineStatements>
           <defineStatement>_unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0</defineStatement>
        </defineStatements>
        <prepareScriptlet>
            <script>./../../../../scripts/rpm/prepare/makeATar.sh</script>
        </prepareScriptlet>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn rpm:rpm` the makeATar script creates a tar in DIRECTORY_FOR_MY_TAR, but it isn't included in my rpm.  If I run `mvn rpm:rpm` again my tar will successfully be include in the rpm (since it was put into DIRECTORY_FOR_MY_TAR from the execution of makeATar the last time I ran `mvn rpm:rpm`).

Answer (score 3):

We also have a similar setup where we build some artifacts and then pack them into an RPM with the **rpm-maven-plugin**.
To arrange the artifacts before we pack as RPM, we

- Use the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) in the **prepare-package** phase to arrange all the aritfacts
- Call the **rpm-maven-plugin** as part of the **package** phase

It works very well for us.
You can also bind the **rpm-maven-plugin** execution to the **install** phase and use the artifacts that were packages in the **package** phase.
**Or** put the RPM packing in a separate maven module and build it after all other modules are already built (and pack their artifacts as planned).

I hope this helps.